# Output Only Field's Name Having Null Values in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I've Table structure as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `credit_limit` (
  `l_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cl_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `used_credit_bal` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `0` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `3` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `4` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `5` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `6` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `7` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `8` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `9` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`l_id`),
  KEY `cl_id` (`cl_id`)
);
```

Now i need only fields to be returned which is Null or 0 in the result set.

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to SO! What have you tried yourself, to accomplish what you need? Also, please consider improving the formatting of your question using the buttons available to you in the toolbar of the question editor. =)

Comment: You can try looping over all the columns (PHP ?) and print only those with Null/0 values. doing it using query will be more challenging.

Comment: Also - since the constraints of your table don't allow -any- field to be NULL, that should make the query easier for you to write. =)

Comment: What are you intending to use the results for? It seems like this is something that would be better handled by whatever language you're using to connect to MySQL.